# Error: Not implemented Trying to create a stream with ExcelJS

Tags: node.js, exceljs

Using Node v 5.4.1

I'm trying to create a stream like so:

```
const program = require('commander'),
      Excel   = require('exceljs'),
      colors  = require('colors/safe'),
      inquirer  = require('inquirer'),
      async    = require('async'),
      stream   = require('stream');

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .usage('[options] <file>')
  .parse(process.argv);

if (program.args.length > 0 && program.args[0]) {
  var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
  var rs       = new stream.Readable();
  rs.pipe(workbook.xlsx.createInputStream()); < -- Error

} else {
  console.log("You did not enter a valid file path");
}
```

But I get the error `Error: Not Implemented`

which I believe is because I have not implemented the `._read` but I thought maybe `workbook.xlsx.createInputStream()` would do this.

Am I using the stream package wrong? Any information would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to do this:

```
var rs = new stream.Readable();
```

Just try:

```
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
stream.pipe(workbook.xlsx.createInputStream());
```